# Left(VLookup) vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with Vlookup.
This code below works as long the code return numbers, but when it is text, it will not retur first 3 letters in text.

Anyone cant solves this promblem?

best regards kjeld

```
Sub test()

Dim AntalO As Integer
Dim AntalM As Integer
Dim res As String 
Dim CountryRange As Range, InitialRange As Range, C As Range

AntalO = Worksheets("ark1").Cells(2, 4).Value    
AntalM = Worksheets("ark1").Cells(4, 4).Value   

Set CountryRange = Sheets("Hoved").Range(Cells(2, 6), Cells(AntalM, 6))    
Set InitialRange = Sheets("ordre").Range("A1:R50000")     

For Each C In CountryRange    
    res = Left(Application.VLookup(C, InitialRange, 19, False), 3)    

    If Not IsError(res) Then   
        C.Offset(0, -1).Value = res
    End If

Next C

End Sub
```

Comment: Vlookup looks for a match with the first column in "InitialRange" If that column has numbers in it then they return a match but text will return an error, and left will not be able to slice the error. You need to ensure that whatever is in C matches the datatype in the lookup table

Answer (score 0):

How about the code below, this will get the first three digits returned by the Vlookup if the value is numeric, but if it is a string then it will return the complete value:

```
Sub test()

Dim AntalO As Integer
Dim AntalM As Integer
Dim res As String
Dim CountryRange As Range, InitialRange As Range, C As Range

AntalO = Worksheets("ark1").Cells(2, 4).Value
AntalM = Worksheets("ark1").Cells(4, 4).Value

Set CountryRange = Sheets("Hoved").Range(Cells(2, 6), Cells(AntalM, 6))
Set InitialRange = Sheets("ordre").Range("A1:R50000")

For Each C In CountryRange

    If IsNumeric(Application.VLookup(C, InitialRange, 19, False), 3) Then
    'if value returned by Vlookup is numeric then
        res = Left(Application.VLookup(C, InitialRange, 19, False), 3)
        'get the first three digits
    Else 'if the value returned is not numeric
        res = Application.VLookup(C, InitialRange, 19, False)
        'return the full value
    End If

    If Not IsError(res) Then
        C.Offset(0, -1).Value = res
    End If

Next C

End Sub
```